# Authentication Error When Cloning GitHub Repository with Fine-Grained Personal Access Token

Tags: git, github, error-handling, token

I'm a newbie to programming and currently undergoing a course on version control. I'm trying to complete a task where I need to create a GitHub repository and then clone it to my local machine. However, I encountered the following error:

```
remote: Permission to solonique69/alx-pre_course.git denied to solonique69.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/solonique69/alx-pre_course.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I've learned that this is an authentication issue. The exercise instructed me to clone the repository using the following format:

```
git clone https://{YOUR_PERSONAL_TOKEN}@github.com/{YOUR_USERNAME}/alx-pre_course.git
```

I followed this format, but I used GitHub's fine-grained Personal Access Token, and I didn't assign any account or repository permissions.

I resolved it by deleting the cloned repository and the Personal Access Token and then recreating a classic Personal Access Code and repository.

How can I resolve this authentication error and successfully clone the repository without deleting files or repository? Also, if I use a fine-grained Personal Access Token what permissions am I to grant?

Comment: Don't put the token in the URL.  That's insecure because it leaves secrets in plaintext in a file.  Instead, use a credential helper.